# CentOS 6, 2 NICs, 1 gateway, 1 NIC doesn't work right

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, linux-networking, nic

I have a CentOS 6 install that had 1 NIC, eth0, working fine

I added another NIC, `eth1`.  Both NICs are on the same switch, and same LAN.

I copied `ifcfg-eth0` to `ifcfg-eth1`, and then simply changed the `DEVICE=`, `IPADDR=`, and `HWADDR=` iines.

After setting up `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`, I can ping `eth1` from an external machine all day and it is fine.

But if I try to ping from inside the server (`ping -Ieth1 google.com`), I get no response, whereas `ping -Ieth0 google.com` works fine.

I have removed the `GATEWAY=` lines from both `ifcfg-eth0` and `ifcfg-eth1`, and put `GATEWAY=` in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Here are my obfuscated config files:

**eth0**
        DEVICE=eth0
        BOOTPROTO=static
    IPADDR=192.168.1.40
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    HWADDR=00:00:23:45:67:8F
    NM_CONTROLLED=no
    ONBOOT=yes
    TYPE=Ethernet
    IPV6INIT=no
    DNS1=192.168.1.240
    DNS2=192.168.1.244

**eth1**
    DEVICE=eth1
    BOOTPROTO=static
    IPADDR=192.168.1.41
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    HWADDR=00:00:23:45:67:99
    NM_CONTROLLED=no
    ONBOOT=yes
    TYPE=Ethernet
    IPV6INIT=no
    DNS1=192.168.1.240
    DNS2=192.168.1.244

**network**
    NETWORKING_IPV6=no
    HOSTNAME=myserver
    NETWORKING=yes
    GATEWAY=192.168.1.2

My `iptables -L -v` are currently completely empty.  And I am not using SELinux.

Comment: Have you tried using the cable connection from ETH1 in ETH0 to verify that your physical connection is up?

Comment: "Both NICs are on the same switch, and same LAN." -- WHY?

Comment: Why not? For routing purposes, each `ethX` will be linked to a different 1to1NAT

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the cable is not the problem.  Remember that I can ping the `eth1` IP just fine from an external machine (which makes no sense).  It is only a ping from inside the machine to an external IP that fails.  I'm not sure how you could successfully ping from outside to inside but not vice versa without an interfering firewall, but the firewall rules are empty...

Comment: If you disable eth0 does eth1 start working?

Comment: Do following test: `ifdown eth0` then ping "eth1 IP" from outside and ping outside (google.com) from inside. Do the same for eth1. Finally turn both nics on and add the output of `route -n` here (obfuscating IPs in the same manner you did earlier). Your server might be routing all outgoing traffic through eth0.

Comment: Can you provide your routing table?

Answer (score 2):

Never ever set two interfaces to the same subnet, this will probably not work as desired. If you examine the output of `ip ro`, you'll understand that Linux is predominantly based on destination-based routing. Although [source-based routing is possible](http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2009/04/15/doing-simple-source-policy-routing-centos/), it is very rare in practice. I can only recall one time when I needed to do it in my life, whatever was the reason.

You misunderstood what `ping -I` does, hence the confusion. From man:

> -I interface address
>
> ```
> Set source address to specified interface address.
> ```

Ping doesn't send the packet trough -I interface. When a packet is ready to be sent out, kernel looks at **destination IP** and `ip ro`, and based on these two things it decides which interface to use. It doesn't look at packet's **source IP**.

-I if for setting the source IP of a packet. As a packet flows out, the switch knows both your IPs came from MAC of eth0, so it sends responses there. But eth0 drops everything that isn't addressed to its own IP (or broadcast). There is no "magical internal bridging" between eth0 and eht1, outside of what you see in the `ip ro`. So the answer never reaches eth1.

The `ip ro` is a modern replacement for deprecated `route`.

Since you use the same switch/gateway, you probably want to have **bonding** of eth0 and eth1. Then set your two IP addresses on bond0 interface (ifcfg-bond0). This is a standard practice and would work as a charm.

To completely separate the traffic between eth0 and eth1, it's best to set eth1 to a different IP subnet, such as 192.168.2.40 and use a different router/gateway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
```

[Packets discarded when the route for outbound traffic differs from the route of incoming traffic](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031)

Comment: A bit more detail might help understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

Daniel -

It appears that your problem exists because of the intented configuration's limitation. You have two interfaces on the same LAN/subnet, but one of them must be the default route. Run this command to verify your route is defaulting to eth0, this will indicate that you will not be able to reach any devices outside your network when you attempt to force traffic through eth1.

```
route
```

It should look something like this:

> Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask       Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> 192.168.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
>
> link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0 
>   0 eth0
>
> default         192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0 
>   0 eth0

For sanity checking, try pinging something local to your LAN through that port:

```
ping -Ieth1 192.168.1.2
```